# Group By Rollup suppress extra line of data

Tags: sql, oracle, null, group-by, rollup

I'm on an Oracle 11g database.

Query:

```
SELECT s.id, s.grade_level, 
((1990+substr(sg.termid,1,2))||'-'||(1991+substr(sg.termid,1,2))) as  "School Year",
SUM(sg.earnedcrhrs) as "Credits"

FROM students s
JOIN storedgrades sg ON s.id = sg.studentid

WHERE s.schoolid = 109
AND s.id = '3466'
AND s.enroll_status = 0
AND sg.schoolid = 109

GROUP BY ROLLUP(s.id, s.grade_level, substr(sg.termid,1,2))
ORDER BY s.id, substr(sg.termid,1,2)
```

Output:

[image]

Is there a way I can write my query such that either line #5 or line #6 is not produced?  I need only a single subtotal per student (the ID column).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky. Try this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.grade_level, 
((1990+substr(sg.termid,1,2))||'-'||(1991+substr(sg.termid,1,2))) as  "School Year",
SUM(sg.earnedcrhrs) as "Credits"

FROM students s
JOIN storedgrades sg ON s.id = sg.studentid

WHERE s.schoolid = 109
AND s.id = '3466'
AND s.enroll_status = 0
AND sg.schoolid = 109

GROUP BY ROLLUP(s.id, (s.grade_level, substr(sg.termid,1,2)))
ORDER BY s.id, substr(sg.termid,1,2);
```

(the difference is that I put `s.grade_level, substr(sg.termid,1,2)` in the `GROUP BY` clause in parentheses)

In general, I highly recommend this article by Tim Hall: [Rollup, Cube and GROUPING functions](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets.php)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get get my hands on a copy of O'Reilly's **Mastering Oracle SQL** by Sanjay Misbra & Alan Beaulieu.  Following their documentation, I actually did this in a slightly different way...

I changed the GROUP BY line from

```
GROUP BY ROLLUP(s.id, s.grade_level, substr(sg.termid,1,2))
```

to

```
GROUP BY s.id, s.grade_level, ROLLUP(substr(sg.termid,1,2))
```